# Ruby IRB - Readline failing to be required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew, irb

I am on a Mac OSx 10.8.

I was an idiot and deleted my opt directory and removed it from trash.  I reinstalled Ruby and openssl via homebrew.  I keep getting the error below when I type 'irb'

**==> irb
Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history install readline then reinstall the ruby.
You may follow 'rvm notes' for dependencies and/or read the docs page https://rvm.io/packages/readline/ . Be sure you 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' to re-compile your ruby with readline support after obtaining the readline libraries.**

I looked at the docs, I tried to install with rvm.  I can't figure out how autolibs is working to get it to install.  I reinstalled ruby 2 times with homebrew.  Checked folder permissions and made it 777.  I am pretty much lost.  Without redline, the 'history' is not working in IRB so using an up arrow or back arrow doesn't work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using homebrew or macports? Sounds like you need to install readline via one of those two apps...

Comment: I had macports on there before.  I installed homebrew after this mess and moved macports.  Unfortunately when I do  brew install redline I get an error too: brew install redline
Error: No available formula for redline 
Searching taps...

Comment: Try RVM:  `rvm pkg install readline --verify-downloads 1`

Comment: you may be able to just install a pure ruby readline, as a workaround...https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline

Comment: Looks like you most have made a typo here, cause you use ``redline`` several times. And I just tried right now, Homebrew does provide a working ``readline`` formula (but no ``redline``, indeed !). 
→ https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/readline.rb

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this error when going to IRB and not being able to have any command line history.

To remedy, I did the following:

```
rvm pkg install readline
```

And then I followed RVM instruction to:

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

(n.b.: Before I did the reinstall, I used `rvm list rubies` to show me everything installed, and took the opportunity to prune older rubies (and their gems) by using `rvm remove <ruby>` and cleaning things up)